# How to fix warnings appeared while using fscanf()?

Tags: c, warnings, scanf

I'm using `fscanf` to read some `int` values from a file. It works correctly, but the way I did it, compiler gives a few warnings.

Source:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
int num;
while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&num) != EOF) // This is the line 46
    printf("%d ",num);
```

Warnings:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘fscanf’ from incompatible pointer type
format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
passing argument 2 of ‘fscanf’ from incompatible pointer type
Line breakpoint: main.c [line: 46]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: redefine prototype of  fscanf, actual code is different E.g `fscanf("%d",&num)`. (before save?)

Comment: Be sure to `#include<stdio.h>` before this code.

Comment: Minor: Use `while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&num) == 1)` rather than `while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&num) != EOF)` to avoid problems when file does not end yet has unconvertible text.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how did u know about it?! yeah i did it long ago, before build and etc. I wrote the line again and that warning just gone. Thank you guys to answer my newbie question!

Comment: Of course, the returned value from fopen() needs to be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redefine prototype of fscanf, actual code is different E.g `fscanf("%d",&num)`. (before save?) – BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

You just need parenthesis

```
while( (fscanf(fp,"%d",&num)) != EOF) // This is the line 46
```